# Particionar o algoritmo em funções

Tags: c, funções, modularização

O problema é o seguinte:

> uma função receba um int como parâmetro, e retorna ele escrito ao contrario e outra para fazer o teste se o numero de entrada e o numero invertido é ou não palíndromo.

Consegui resolver o problema de identificar se o número de entrada é palíndromo, mas falta me dividir o código em funções de acordo com o que foi pedido.

Até o momento o meu código está assim:

```
int i, j;

scanf("%d", &i);

int n = i;
int l = 0;

while(n != 0){
    j = n % 10;
    l = (l * 10) + j;
    n = n / 10;
}

if(i == l)
    printf("sim");
else
    printf("nao");
```

Comment: E o código não está como pretende ? O que faltou fazer ? A parte do palindromo funciona corretamente. Basta testar com alguns numeros como `313`, `123`, `123321`

Comment: não estar como pretendo. o que não tenho dificuldades é em dividir o código em função. por exemplo: int inverte...

Comment: Escolha um nome melhor do que `l` pra sua variável. Em fontes monospaced (que usamos pra programar) parece o dígito `1`.

Comment: @Gabriel, tem pratica de usar variáveis nessa sequência,(independente do problema), i, j, l, m, n, o ..., mas comento cada umas das dependendo do problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separei a parte de interação com o usuário com o algoritmo em si e fiz a comunicação através de parâmetro e retorno.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Inverte(int n) { //n é um parâmetro que recebe o que foi passado (digitado)
    int l = 0, j;
    while (n != 0) {
        j = n % 10;
        l = (l * 10) + j;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return l; //retorna o valor invertido que poderá ser usado onde precisa
}
int main(void) {
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf(i == Inverte(i) ? "sim" : "nao"); //em vez de comparar uma variável verifica com o retorno da função que é chamada com o que foi digitado como argumento
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/lA6QiQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hcpltsjf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Modularization.c).

Comment: o retorno ficou bem mais claro agora e o que passar pra função Inverte.